VBA code is not copying the full set of data
The below code is supposed to copy all matching REGION rows with e.g. ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST), but for some reason it doesn't do anything if the first row (non-header) is not "ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)".

Sub copy_data()

Dim count_col As Integer
Dim count_row As Integer
Dim og As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim region As String

Set og = Sheet1
region = og.Cells(1, 1).Text

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = region

og.Activate
count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=region

og.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)). _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wb.Sheets(region).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
og.ShowAllData
og.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub


If the first row contains ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST), it stops at the second row etc.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator. What's content in cell A4? Your code manipulates two sheets, please qualify all Range object (Range(), Cells()) with sheet object.


Cells(count_row, count_col) is not the bottom-right cell of the table because the table doesn't start from A1. For your scenario, count_row=8 and count_col=4. The autofilter is applied to the range A4:D8
, excluding the desired rows where the Region is ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST).

og.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col))



The code manipulates two sheets, please qualify all Range object (Range(), Cells()) with sheet object.

Activate is not necessary, pls read:


How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)

Sub copy_data()
    
    Dim count_col As Long
    Dim count_row As Long
    Dim og As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet
    Dim region As String
    Const START_CELL = "A4"
    Set og = Sheet1
    region = og.Cells(1, 1).Text
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    sht.Name = region
    
    With og.Range(START_CELL)
        count_col = .End(xlToRight).Column
        count_row = og.Cells(og.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=region
        .Resize(count_row, count_col).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With
    sht.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    og.ShowAllData
    og.AutoFilterMode = False
    
End Sub



If the table is sperated range (ie. the table is surrounded by blank rows and cols), you can use CurrentRegion.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

    With og.Range(START_CELL)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=region
        .CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With


Thank you, also for explaining why the above did not work! For background: I used a youtube video which specified the code above.
When you write "please qualify all Range object (Range(), Cells()) with sheet object.", are you referring for example to this line " With og.Range(START_CELL)"?

I've added note for CurrentRegion. It may be helpful for you too.

Range(START_CELL) is equalient to ActiveSheet.Range(START_CELL), but the ActiveSheet may not be the intended sheet. Therefore, it is better and more reliable to always use <SheetObject>.Range(..).
